# Ember.js click action that changes object property

Tags: object, properties, click, ember.js

Basically, I have a template that displays a list of `Objects` within an `ArrayController`. Each listed item will have a button that should update a property for that specific `Object`. I feel like I'm making this more difficult than it is, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the HTML with the template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{view App.MainView}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item_template">
      {{#view App.addButtonView}}
          <div id="add_button"><span>Add Item</span></div>
      {{/view}}

      <div id="item_list">
          {{#each App.itemsController}}
              <div class="item_title">{{title}}</div>
                  {{#view App.updateTitleBtnView}}
                       <div class="title_btn">UPDATE THE TITLE</div>
                  {{/view}}
              </div>
          {{/each}}
      </div>
  </script>
```

Then my script is this:

```
var App = Em.Application.create({
    ready:function(){
        this.itemsController.createItem();
    }
});

App.Item=Em.Object.extend({
    title:"An Item"
});

App.itemsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    createItem: function(){
        var item = App.Item.create();
        this.pushObject(item);
    }
});


App.addButtonView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(){
          App.itemsController.createItem();
    }
});

App.updateTitleBtnView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(){

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Change the value of the title property for a single Object //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }
});

App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'item_template'
});
```

What code do I need to include in the view: `App.updateTitleBtnView`? Am I going about any of this in the right way?

I am new to Ember, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the handlebars [{{action}}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_action) handler.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{view App.MainView}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item_template">
  <button id="add_button" {{action addItem}}>Add Item</button>

  <div id="item_list">
      {{#each item in App.itemsController}}
          <div class="item_title">{{item.title}}</div>
          <a href="#" {{action updateTitle item}}>UPDATE THE TITLE</a>
      {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

And put all the view logic on your App.MainView for now.

```
App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'item_template',
  addItem: function(event){
    App.itemsController.createItem();
  },
  updateTitle: function(event){
    event.context.updateTitle()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I actually update the "title" property on that specific object though?

Comment: I just updated the example, you can pass an object through as the second argument to the action helper and it is made available as the context property on the event.

Comment: Sorry it took me a few days to test this, but anyway the code worked great. There is one minor problem that threw me off though. It seems `{{title}}` should be `{{item.title}}`.

I'll accept your answer as soon as you make that change. Thanks again.

Comment: Good catch, that was left over from when I was just using the default context. I just #each item in ... to be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CollectionView` for this..

```
    var App = Em.Application.create();

    App.itemsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
        content: [],
        createItem: function(){
            this.pushObject(
                Ember.Object.create({title:"old Title"})
            );
        }
    });

    App.MainView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
      contentBinding: 'App.itemsController.content'
      itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        update: ->
            this.get('content').set('title', "Updated Title")
      })
    })

    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      <a {{action createItem target="App.itemsController"}} href="#">Add Item</a>
      {{#collection App.MainView}}
        Title: {{view.content.title}}
        <a {{action update}} href="#"> Update Title </a>
      {{/collection}}
    </script>
```